# AWS API Gateway dynamic StageName for CICD

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, gitlab-ci, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I'm trying to deploy an AWS API Gateway using Gitlab CICD pipelines. Since I have different environments, I want the **StageName** property of the API to be set dynamically i.e., StageName should be "dev" when deployed to dev stack, "prod" when deployed to prod stack. Below is the YAML script I used.

```
Mappings:
  StackEnv:
    dev-stack:
      envm: "dev"
    qa-stack:
      envm: "qa"
Resources:  
  TestingAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: [!FindInMap [StackEnv, !Ref AWS::StackName, envm]]
```

It looks fine from above but when I try to deploy the API, I'm getting the error mentioned below.

```
[InvalidResourceException('TestingAPI', "Type of property 'StageName' is invalid.")]
```

I can't seem to understand why it should fail. If this approach won't work, how can I pass the respective environment values to the **StageName** property without breaking the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrapping the results of the `!FindInMap` function in `[]` making it a list.  Remove the brackets:

```
      StageName: !FindInMap [StackEnv, !Ref AWS::StackName, envm]
```